# NotificationServiceExtension with multiple targets in iOS Application

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have 3 targets in my iOS application namely Stage, Preprod and Prod. I added NotificationServiceExtension for the Stage target for the development purpose. Since the added NotificationServiceExtension is not available in other targets i.e pre-prod and prod, hence am not able to use the NotificationServiceExtension. Do i have to added 2 more NotificationServiceExtension for Preprod and prod targets? Or there is some different solution? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to avoid using different targets for different environments. The better way is to use different build configurations, because:

1. .xcodeproj file will be much smaller
2. You will need single app extension
3. You will not need to add each new file to every target
4. You will not need to recompile the whole app for different environment

So in your case I'd create the following configs:

1. StageDebug
2. StageRelease
3. PreprodDebug
4. PreprodRelease
5. ProdDebug
6. ProdRelease

[Here is a nice article](https://www.talentica.com/blogs/ios-build-management-using-custom-build-scheme/) about creating build configurations, have a look.